# Change the label of a standard field of PriceBookEntry object

Tags: administration, pricebookentry

Is it possible to change the label of a field (in my case I'd like to change the label of the UnitPrice field) of the PriceBookEntry standard object ?

In the setup -> tabs and labels, I don't see the PricebookEntry object (but I can see the PriceBook object...)
Do you know if it's possible for this object ?

Answer (score 1):

You can relabel / rename the Pricebook Entry field, List Price!

Setup > Rename Tabs & Labels > Opportunity Products > Edit > Next > Standard Field Labels > List Price

It turns out, when you rename the field in the Opp Product, it also renames it in the Pricebook Entry object.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the label of a standard field on PriceBookEntry object on the UI or using Metadata API. When you make an attempt through the Metadata API, you will receive the following error

Error: Could not resolve standard field's name

```
 <fields>
    <fullName>UnitPriceFieldChange</fullName>
    <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
</fields>
<fields>
    <fullName>UseStandardPrice</fullName>
    <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
</fields>
```

[image]

**Note**: The label for Custom field can be changed on PriceBookEntry object

Comment: Ok so the answer is no we can't change it... I hoped that we could do so since it's possible for other standard objects, but I will have to keep it like that. Thanks.